Is it possible to supply a hybrid inverter AC input from its own AC output?
As in the diagram below, will it be possible to give the inverter an AC supply coming from its own AC output?


Why do you want to do this?

Does you inverter produce AC out without AC in? Mine does not, it needs the grid AC to synchronize.

Mine does. It can give AC Output when connected to either PV or grid or DC source.

It would make very little sense to do so.

If there is automatic switchover on mains failure, it would cause oscillation: power fails => inverter starts => input detects power => inverter shuts.
It wastes power, if the inverter is online continuously. The best inverters might be 85 or 90% efficient. Attempting to charge its own batteries reduces efficiency by losses in the charging circuit, and by losses in the inverter.


No, people tend to get laughed at when talking about above unity gain, aka Perpetual Motion machines. This is the basis of many scams and cons. Everything in a power system is less than 100 percent efficient. It is physically impossible for a system to generate more energy than it consumes. It is diminishing returns. It violates the first and second laws of Thermal Dynamics. Please do not try it; you will burn up your equipment, can cause a fire, and severe burn injuries from the arc flash.

This isn't an overunity thing; the inverter uses external AC input to power some parts on it, but produces its outputs using DC power received from solar cells.
